# Automorphism group of a surface group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

Let $$S_g = \langle a_1,b_1,...,a_g,b_g \mid \prod_{i=1}^g[a_i,b_i] = 1 \rangle$$ be the fundamental group of a genus $g$ orientable surface.  Is there a nice description of the automorphism group of $S_g$?  In particular I would love a nice finite swet of generators.

Comment: People typically study not the automorphism group but the outer automorphism group, which can be identified with the mapping class group; you can look up that keyword for information. There is a nice collection of generators called Dehn twists. You can also handle the case $g = 1$ separately.

Comment: The full automorphism group is the same as the mapping class group of the once punctured genus g surface. The standard textbook covering mapping class groups currently is "Primer on the mapping class group" by Farb and Margalit.